# Scroll top al cambiar de ruta en Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, scroll

Me sucede que estoy viendo una lista de elementos, y al clickear en cualquiera de ellos me dirijo a una nueva ruta donde tengo una vista mas completa de dicho elemento.

Si en la lista, yo scrolleo hacia abajo, al clickear en un elemento y abrirse la vista del mismo, esta se encuentra en una posición de scroll igual a la de la lista (es decir, si yo bajo demasiado en la lista, al entrar a ver el elemento estoy posicionado en el footer del sitio).

Para evitar esto intenté:

1. Que antes de montarse la vista del elemento individual ocurra un window.scrollTo(0,0)
2. Que antes de desmontarse la lista de elementos, ocurra un window.scrollTo(0,0)
3. Según vi en la documentación de `router` hice esto:

   ```
   const router = createRouter({
     scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
       return { top: 0 }
     }
   })
   ```

> Con los 3 intentos me sucede lo mismo. Primero entra a la vista del elemento (scroll abajo), y luego veo como el scroll sube recorriendo toda la página.

**Hay alguna forma de que el scroll se posicione arriba antes de cargar el componente??**

Comment: ¿En qué ciclo de vida estás intentando hacer el `window.scrollTo(0,0)`? Podrías intentar hacerlo entro del [setup()](https://lenguajejs.com/vuejs/componentes/composition-api/#preparaci%C3%B3n-setup), que es de los primeros hooks en ejecutarse, para ver si así evitas que se vea la transición de subida de la página.

Comment: sip, el setup reemplaza el onCreated pero sucede lo mismo (gracias por la aclaración, me faltó agregar en la pregunta que también probé esa opción), se renderiza la página con scroll al final, y luego sube

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto en el router:

```
    {
        path: '/random',
        name: 'random-component',
        component: RandomComponent,
        beforeEnter: (to, from) => {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).